# processing multiple extensions

Tags: bash, filenames, wildcards

I have done a script to convert recursive .jpg files to another size:

```
echo $re
mkdir "$re"_tmp
for a in *.jpg ; do convert "$a" -resize $re "$re""_tmp/${a%.*} ["$re"].jpg" ; done
```

I'd like integrate a multi extension support: png, bmp, etc. better with:

```
FILEFORMAT="jpg, JPG, png, PNG, bmp, BMP"
```

any idea to build it?

PS: variable re is the new size 1024x768 (or 800x600, etc)

Comment: I hope you would consider processing files matching `*.jpeg` as well. Apparently someone in the distant past thought it should be `*.jpg` and this misnomer caught on in a big way... but it seems quite wrong: as if the Joint Photographic Experts Group became the Joint Photographic Group, the implication being that they're not experts!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If I understand right, you want to process files with other extension, instead of only `jpg`. So you can try:

```
for a in *.{jpg,JPG,png,PNG,bmp,BMP}; do
  printf '%s\n' "$a"
  # do your stuff here
done
```

`{...}` is bash feature called [brace expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html).

Comment: thanks for help. I've added your suggestion but the script process only jpg files... strange...

Comment: Are you sure all your file is in the same folder? What is your bash version?

Comment: Hi, version of bash is 4.3-7 (debian testing) and yes, the files are on same folder. I know that the script rename all files to jpg but this is not a problem. Thanks

Comment: @PolHallen: With your bash version, brace expansion will work. So does it work now?

Comment: @Gnouc - are you certain this is not just an interactive shell thing? Also, even if not, it will very likely not work if the `#!` is for `sh`. It would be much simpler to do: `set -- *.[jJ][pP][gG] *.[bB][mM][pP] *.[pP][nN][gG]; for pic do...;done` which would keep the file list in `"$@"` for multiple process loops as necessary.

Comment: @mikeserv: I am waiting for OP to confirm the brace expansion work or not, I then think about solution like yours, because it may be more difficult for OP to understand it than brace expansion only.

Comment: Sorry for mistake :-( I had /bin/myscript indeed the new script had to /home/user/bin/myscript. Thanks for help!

Comment: Hooray! That's good to know - I thought the brace expansion was by default not interpreted unless at a prompt even with a `#!/bin/bash` bang. Thanks, Gnouc.

Comment: This approach doesn't seem to work for me: If a certain extension does not match (say no `*.JPG` file) the for loop variable `a` takes the value of the pattern itself e.g. `*.JPG`. The matching cases are returned properly. Is there a way suppress returning the non-matching patterns?

Comment: Note that it won't work if there are spaces. echo foo.{a,b,c} will work echo foo.{a, b, c} will not. (note spaces after commas).

Answer (score 2):

You may use multiple GLOB expressions separated by space:

```
for a in *.[jJ][pP][gG] \
         *.[jJ][pP][eE][gG] \
         *.[pP][nN][gG] \
         *.[bB][mM][pP]
do
    echo "$a" "$re/$a"
done

# or inline
for a in *.[jJ][pP][gG] *.[jJ][pP][eE][gG] *.[pP][nN][gG] *.[bB][mM][pP] ; do echo "$a" "$re/$a"; done
```

Not sure if it is POSIX compatible, but I believe it is.

Comment: The only thing *not POSIX* in there would be the usage of `echo` which is unspecified for arguments containing arbitrary sequences of bytes such as filenames. See also [Why is printf better than echo?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803). Another potential problem is that in POSIX compliant shells (and that is a misfeature from the Bourne shell specified by POSIX), the `*.[jJ][pP][gG]` expands to `*.[jJ][pP][gG]` if there's no matching file (so you could end up processing a file by that name).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas, thank you for the explanation, seems to use GLOB is not a good idea. I wonder if using find util is better? For example: `for f in $(find . -maxdepth 1 -type f \( -iname '*.bmp' -or -iname '*.png' -or -iname '*.jpeg' -or -iname '*.jpg' \) ) ; do printf "%s\n" "$f" ; done`

Comment: Note that `-iname` is not POSIX. See also [Why is looping over find's output bad practice?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/321697). In your glob loop, you can always filter out non-matches or non-regular files with an extra `[ -f "$a" ] || continue`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a POSIX complaint variant:

```
for a in *.jp* *.JP*; do
  [ -f "$a" ] || continue
  echo "Processing $a"
done
```

1. In POSIX you may put multiple GLOBs separated by space
2. In real life extensions are ether in lower case `jpg` or in upper `JPG` but not with mixed case.
3. If no any `JPG` files then the glob wont be expanded and the var `a` will have `*.JP*` value. You must filter out it by checking that hte file is exists with the `[ -f "$a" ]`

Comment: This wrongly matches files like `foo.jp` and `bar.jpbaz`.